# How to assign a number to a Line in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void DrawLine(Canvas canvas, Point pt1, Point pt2, Brush lineColor, double lineThickness)
{
        Line line = new Line();
        line.Stroke = lineColor;
        line.StrokeThickness = lineThickness;
        line.X1 = pt1.X;
        line.Y1 = pt1.Y;
        line.X2 = pt2.X;
        line.Y2 = pt2.Y;
        canvas.Children.Add(line);
}
```

The function above draws a line on canvas. Is it possible to add some information to the line(e.g. an int) so that I can use it when the user clicks the line? For example, I want to use this function to draw many lines, and I want to assign a number (called NUM) to each line. Once the user clicks the line, I will run hittest so that I know which line the user choose, and set the color of all lines that has the same NUM to Black.

Comment: There are lots of options. But really, you should not be doing your own hit-testing. WPF already provides that functionality for you. You should instead be using MVVM, where the view model provides a handler for click events based on the WPF hit-testing, and the view model will of course _be_ the object you want, rather than requiring some mechanism to find that object you want based on the view object.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with `Tag` and the help of Mouse Events `sender` field

```
((Line)sender).Tag
```

**Example**

```
Line line = new Line();
line.Tag = "Some Value";
line.MouseUp += (sender, args) =>
                  {
                     var myValue = ((Line)sender).Tag;
                     Debug.WriteLine($"My value : {myValue}");
                  };
```

---

**Additional Resource**

[Line Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.line(v=vs.110).aspx)

[FrameworkElement.Tag Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Remarks** : This property is analogous to Tag properties in other
>   Microsoft programming models, such as Microsoft Visual Basic for
>   Applications (VBA) or Windows Forms. Tag is intended to provide a
>   pre-existing property location where you can store some basic custom
>   information about any FrameworkElement without requiring you to
>   subclass an element.

Futhermore

> Because this property takes an object, you would need to use the
>   property element usage in order to set the Tag property in Extensible
>   Application Markup Language (XAML) to anything other than an object
>   with a known and built-in type converter, such as a string. Objects
>   used in this manner are typically not within the standard Windows
>   Presentation Foundation (WPF) namespaces and therefore may require
>   namespace mapping to the external namespace in order to be introduced
>   as XAML elements. For details, see XAML Namespaces and Namespace
>   Mapping for WPF XAML and XAML and Custom Classes for WPF.